# change the download directory without the popup window at chrome

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I am using Selenium and Java to write tests for Chrome browser. At some point i need to download a file and I need to change the directory that file is gonna be downloaded to. the problem is that when I use the code snippet below it opens the popup window and I don't want it:

```
String downloadFilepath = "download";
HashMap<String, Object> chromePrefs = new HashMap<String, Object>();
chromePrefs.put("download.default_directory", downloadFilepath);
options.setExperimentalOption("prefs", chromePrefs);
```

Comment: Don't you think that `downloadFilepath` requires more than just a name?

Comment: @FlorentB that's not the point, I wrote it as an example of a file path

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add below arguments as chromeOptions :-

```
options.addArguments("disable-popup-blocking")
```

Hope it will help you..:)

Comment: Your question is absolutely right..there is no reason for down vote..I think @florentB couldn't get your question properly... perhaps he think that you are putting downloadFilepath just a name insteadof putting actual path..I think that's the reason...If I'm right..this is your bad luck...

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this?

```
String downloadFilepath = "download";
 Map<String, Object> prefs = new HashMap<String, Object>();
 prefs.put("download.default_directory", downloadFilepath);
 DesiredCapabilities caps = DesiredCapabilities.chrome();
 ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
 options.setExperimentalOption("prefs", prefs);
 caps.setCapability(ChromeOptions.CAPABILITY, options);
```